# Error in Output Window - Managed' has exited with code -2147023895 (0x800703e9)

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, memory-management, thread-safety, managed

I am unable to run a windows application in Visual Studio 2008. Program has been working fine until I started getting an error in the Output Window - "
The program '[2260] MUS3.vshost.exe: Managed' has exited with code -2147023895 (0x800703e9). "  This happens even before execution of the code begins.

Any help ? Thanks in Advance

I am placing the entire error here

> 'MUS3.vshost.exe' (Managed): Loaded
>   'D:\Documents and
>   Settings\Administrator\Desktop\MUS
>   TEMP\trunk\Dev\Source\Source\Binaries\MUS3.exe',
>   Symbols loaded. Ignoring managed
>   exception from unknown thread.The
>   program '[2260] MUS3.vshost.exe:
>   Managed' has exited with code
>   -2147023895 (0x800703e9).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Hell, this is not quite an answer, but at least it might help someone. I met with something like the above problem, but in Visual Studio 2005 Pro SP1. Everything had been working and then suddenly nothing worked.
I tried all sorts of different things and ideas... even tried simply creating a new windows application and trying to start it in debug mode (same thing happened, same message appeared - my heart broke seeing the following output again and again from the VS debug output window:

```
'WindowsApplication1.exe' (Managed): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_32\mscorlib\2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\mscorlib.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
Process is terminated due to StackOverflowException.
Ignoring managed exception from unknown thread.The program '[1856] WindowsApplication1.exe: Managed' has exited with code -2147023895 (0x800703e9).
```

Even thought that i maybe messed the .NET versions on my computer. Well, but at least in my case things finally were much simpler, and maybe this applies for my case only (silly me) - but somehow in Application Properties -> Debug tab, the radio button named "Enable unmanaged code debugging" was unchecked. After checking it, more "libraries" seem to be loaded, albeit with no symbols....

and...

magically the program is started normally and the debugger actually steps in on a breakpoint. i don't quite know or suspect why this think worked out like this - any suggestions are welcome!

Answer (score 1):

This Error occurred mostly at that when you move your code from one version of visual studio to another latest version.
In older version if you are using latest framework like 4.5 
At initial stage Warning  is `!(Your Application Not Target the Exact Framework)`

Then First you should target the Framework(Click on Project rather than Solution go to `properties ->Application` set your framework)

Then clean and rebuild. If not working then You should use a `Window Form` which not manipulate any data from DataBase or create a new folder, in that folder create a new Form then this from Run through the main function. I hope this will work 
78692110

Answer (score 0):

if you're using .net 2013, then go to project, then at the property windows go to references and add the  references for the Microsoft ADO Data Control ,it will work now